# realtime effects on a video component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, videodisplay, video-effects

I have a flex 4.5 application that uses a `mx:VideoDisplay` component to display the webcam.
how can I add realtime effects to that VideoDisplay component ?

for example:
changing colors, particle/grain looks, wave effects, zoom and so on

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing colours can be done using any of the mx.graphics.shaderClasses.* by applying a blendMode

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/shaderClasses/package-detail.html